# What does the membership automatic renewal interface look like?

Tags: civimember

Where do I get the option to choose whether to renew a membership automatically? Secondly, how does it only apply to the initial membership?

I have

- installed a recurring payments processor (agileware eway)
- in the membership type configurations page I've made auto-renew optional
- I've tried the page, both logged in and not logged in.

Where should I see this choice?

Answer (score 2):

After you've made the membership type as optional, you should set an additional setting on the contribution page, i.e,

- visit Contributions -> Manage Contribution Pages
- Go to the `Membership` tab of the required contribution page.
- You will see an additional column of `Auto-Renew` on the `Membership type` field.

[image]

- Select `Give Option` on the membership type that you want to enable this option for.
- Save and Navigate to the live contribution link `civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=<page_id>`. This should display an option to renew the membership.

[image]